# JSON string interpolation from argument in Dockerfile

Tags: json, dockerfile, string-interpolation

```
ARG consumer-key
ARG consumer-secret

ENV COMPOSER_AUTH '{ "bitbucket-oauth": { "bitbucket.org": { "consumer-key": "${consumer-key}", "consumer-secret": "${consumer-secret}" } } }'
```

```
docker build \
--build-arg consumer-key=test \
--build-arg consumer-secret=test \
.
```

The values of `consumer-key` and `consumer-secret` are not replaced with the build arguments

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, please rename your arguments using underscores:

```
ARG consumer_key
ARG consumer_secret
```

Then, using single quotes around the argument variables properly interpolates them into the string:

```
ENV COMPOSER_AUTH '{ "bitbucket-oauth": { "bitbucket.org": { "consumer-key": "'$consumer_key'", "consumer-secret": "'$consumer_secret'" } } }'
```

Finally, change your *docker build* command accordingly:

```
docker build \
--build-arg consumer_key=test \
--build-arg consumer_secret=test \
.
```

Comment: single quote doesnt help :(

Comment: @EfratLevitan I've done this repeatedly and it does work for me. Could you describe your problem?

Comment: @KRailis i was trying to have multiline json in the Dockerfile. but you where right about single line. maybe add this reservation to your answer, unless you have any solution for my case?

Comment: @EfratLevitan On the other hand, this answer solves the problem in question, and I do not believe that down-voting an answer for not solving a question that _has not been asked_ is exactly fair.

Comment: you are right. Unfortunately i cant change this anymore